# Find all parents of given ids in tree in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, tree, common-table-expression

I have a tree structure in single table and item relationships in another table. I need to find out all the parents from the given items.

```
SELECT Id FROM dbo.Items WHERE Selected = 1
```

Since I get 6,9, 11 from that query, I would need to return parent item ids of those which are 7, 5, 2.

[image]

I think I should use some kind of recursive CTE for this, but I'm not sure where to start.

Could you help me out? Thanks!

```
dbo.Relationship
Id       ParentId
3           6
6           7
8           7
7           2
4           9
9           5
5           2   


dbo.Items
Id              Selected
2                   0
3                   0
4                   0
5                   0
6                   1
7                   0
8                   0
9                   1
11                  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to get all the parent of selected items?
I changed to use temporary table.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#Relationship') is not null drop table #Relationship
create table #Relationship(Id int,ParentId int)
insert into #Relationship(Id,ParentId)
SELECT 3,6 UNION
SELECT 6,7 UNION
SELECT 8,7 UNION
SELECT 7,2 UNION
SELECT 4,9 UNION
SELECT 9,5 UNION
SELECT 5,2
if object_id('tempdb..#items') is not null drop table #items
create table #items(Id int, Selected bit)
insert into #items(Id,Selected)
SELECT 2,0 UNION
SELECT 3,0 UNION
SELECT 4,0 UNION
SELECT 5,0 UNION
SELECT 6,1 UNION
SELECT 7,0 UNION
SELECT 8,0 UNION
SELECT 9,1 UNION
SELECT 11,1

;with cte AS (
   SELECT i.ID AS SelectedID,r.ParentId FROM #Items AS i INNER JOIN #Relationship AS r ON i.id=r.id WHERE i.Selected=1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT cte.SelectedID, r.ParentId FROM #Relationship AS r INNER JOIN CTE ON CTE.ParentId=r.id
)
SELECT * FROM cte ORDER BY cte.SelectedID
```

Can it give you some help?

```
SelectedID  ParentId
----------- -----------
6           7
6           2
9           5
9           2
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to return, but can you tell me how I can replace all the "SELECT  {number}, {number} UNION" statements with simple SELECT Id, Selected FROM Items. Maybe that's a stupid question.

Comment: @Pegaz You can ignore the Relationship  and Items with statement, It just like a temporary table, you just replace them with your table name in the CTE sub statement.

Answer (score 1):

Left Join on the related Id between Items and Relations.

```
SELECT 
    Items.Id, 
    Relationship.ParentId 
FROM Items
LEFT JOIN Relationship ON Relationship.Id = Items.Id
```

I have used this in the past to get all parent Ids:

```
with compParent as
(
    select * from Component Where ComponentId = @ComponentId
    union all
    select Component.* from Component join compParent on Component.ComponentId = 
    compParent.ContainerParentId
)

select * from compParent;
```

I have used this to get all children:

```
with compChild as
(
    select * from Component where ComponentId = @ParentId
    union all
    select Component.* from Component join compChild on Component.ContainerParentId = compChild.ComponentId
)


select * from compChild;
```

You can also look at the many stackOverFlow posts that are already out there to get parent and/or children. Or a simple google search for "SQL Server Get Parents"